How to manipulate modules in PyCharm
In IntelliJ there is this File -> Project structure that I can't find PyCharm.
I try to add two Poetry modules:

.venv from the root directory of the project
.venv from the subdirectory of the same project

Intellij Version of the dialog window
In intellij I can do it with `Cmd+;` in Pycharm there is no such shortcut.
In PyCharm where is this window that is present in IntelliJ as presented above?
I tried searching menu but no such option present

PyCharm does not have such a panel.

IntelliJ IDEA's core project architecture is multi-modular; other JetBrains IDEs' projects are single-module. That is just how it is.
Thus, each PyCharm project can only have one virtual environment (a.k.a. SDK). Workarounds include:

Use IntelliJ IDEA with the Python plugin, or
Open each subdirectory as a new project.

